# runnserver works fine but apache not

Tags: django, apache, captcha

apache2.2 + django1.8

After I add django-simple-captcha to this project

when I start server by

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

everything goes fine

but when I start it by apache

It shows the error: "The _imagingft C module is not installed."

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What way of deployment for apache do you use? `mod_uwsgi`? Proxy to a uwsgi server like `uwsgi` or `gunicorn`? You are obviously missing the imaging library though and need to install it. Have a web-search. Many people had the same issue already.

Comment: @Christopher Schäpers:I use mod_wsgi, and if the reason is lacking of library then why it works fine after starting server by "runserver" command?

Comment: Is it possible that apache is pointing to a different python, one without the library?

Comment: @Rob L:Could you tell me how can I tell it ?

Comment: Not exactly, but I would start with making sure `httpd.conf` has `WSGIDaemonProcess` `WSGIProcessGroup` and `WSGIScriptAlias` set correctly.